# Obtener el nombre correspondiente al menor valor de edad

Tags: python

Buenas tardes Amigos,

Les agradezco de antemano la ayudan que me puedan brindar, pues soy principiante en programación.

Resulta que tengo un diccionario con unos datos de nombres con sus respectivas edades y estaturas, y requiero obtener el dato de la menor EDAD y su nombre correspondiente.

Pero no he podido obtenerlo, no sé en qué estoy fallando.

```
for key in DATOS.values():
   
    if num > menor:
        num =(DATOS[key]["EDAD"])
        menor= num
        for key, num in DATOS.items():
              if  key in num:
                    Nomb=key
              print(Nomb)   
   print(menor, Nomb)
```

Comment: ¿Qué error es el que te manda? ¿Podrías agregarlo a tu pregunta, de favor?

Answer (score 2):

Soy nuevo en este foro pero creo que puedo echarte una mano, suponiendo que tienes la siguiente estructura de datos este es el enfoque que yo le daría.

```
prueba = {"Ale":{"Edad":20},
          "Pedro":{"Edad":25},
          "Ana":{"Edad":26},
          "Raul":{"Edad":15}}


def encontrarMenor(diccionario):
    menor = 0
    for usuario in diccionario:
        if diccionario[usuario]["Edad"] < menor or not menor:
            menor = diccionario[usuario]["Edad"]
            nombre = usuario
    return(nombre,menor)


print(encontrarMenor(prueba))
```

Recorres el diccionario entero comprobando las edades y devolviendo el de menor edad, tenga en cuenta que en caso de que hubiera varias personas con la misma edad y quiera devolver una lista entera no podría así que lo solucionaría devolviendo una lista de los nombres y la edad de ellos.

```
def encontrarMenor2(diccionario):
    menor = 0
    nombres = []
    for usuario in diccionario:
        if diccionario[usuario]["Edad"] <= menor or not menor:
            menor = diccionario[usuario]["Edad"]
            nombres.append(usuario)
    return(nombres,menor)



print(encontrarMenor2(prueba))
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a stackoverflow, buena respuesta, gracias por ayudar :)

Answer (score 0):

Una manera muy buena de obtener el mínimo puede ser utilizar la función `min`, ya que está pensada para eso.

Para ello puedes combinarla con una función `lambda` en su argumento `key` que puedes modificar en función de la estructura de tu diccionario.

Ya que no has puesto la estructura que sigue tu diccionario, te pongo un par de ejemplos para que veas que puedes adaptarla a lo que necesitas:

```
dicc_1 = {'Juan': [20, 1.70], 
          'Alvaro': [25, 1.75], 
          'Elena': [22, 1.68], 
          'Ana': [30, 1.73]}

menor_edad = min(dicc_1, key=lambda x: dicc_1[x][0])
menor_altura = min(dicc_1, key=lambda x: dicc_1[x][1])

print(menor_edad)  # Devuelve Juan
print(menor_altura)  # Devuelve Elena
```

Si quisieras en este caso obtener la edad de Juan por ejemplo, podrías poner:

```
print(dicc_1[menor_edad][0])  # Devuelve 20
```

Otro caso con un diccionario con estructura diferente:

```
dicc_2 = {'Juan': {'edad': 20, 'estatura': 1.70},
          'Alvaro': {'edad': 25, 'estatura': 1.75},
          'Elena': {'edad': 22, 'estatura': 1.68},
          'Ana': {'edad': 30, 'estatura': 1.73}}

menor_edad = min(dicc_1, key=lambda x: dicc_2[x]['edad'])
menor_altura = min(dicc_1, key=lambda x: dicc_2[x]['estatura'])
   
print(menor_edad)  # Devuelve Juan
print(menor_altura)  # Devuelve Elena
```

Solo tienes que adaptar la función `lambda` para que apunte al dato que quieres que sea el mínimo.